# Styling paper-button Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

I'm a noob in styling. All I want to do is make this button look small.
[image]

And here's my css code:

[image]

Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried decreasing height by half and padding by 1px and font-size something 10px

Comment: works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I ca't tag you tho Yonas Hailu :)

Comment: No problem @IsaiahJanCaracolNavasquez glad you found it work.